# "Failed to build bitarray cytoolz lru-dict" while Installing Web3

Tags: python, web3py, bitarray

After running the command in Windows 10 - `python -m pip install web3` the following error appears - **"Failed to build bitarray cytoolz lru-dict"**.

I resolved the issue by installing Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 and running the command - `python -m pip install python-dev-tools`

Why is python-dev-tools necessary in the process?

Answer (score 0):

Download the Visual Studio Build tools 2019, and install all the dependencies.

Check the "Desktop development with C++" button, and then on the right-hand side where you have the Installation details.

Open the "Desktop development with C++" dropdown, then select the "Windows 1X SDK" the latest version, also select the "C++ CMake tools for Windows" scroll down and include the ">NET build tools" click download and install.